# Is there an easy way to update img src attributes when moving to a new server?

Tags: navigation, migrations, media, updating

I recently copied my site from the dev server to a test server, and I noticed that a lot of images which were placed using the Media module have `src=` attributes that point to the old server.  Ie., `<img src='http://oldsite.com'...>` I don't see any settings within the configurable options for the Media module which will update the links.

I know that WordPress has a handy link updater plug-in called Velvet Blue, or something like that.  Does anyone know of a similar module for Drupal?

Comment: Just for the record.. What Drupal version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Pathologic](https://drupal.org/project/pathologic) module.

> Pathologic is an input filter which can correct paths in links and
>   images in your Drupal content in situations which would otherwise
>   cause them to “break;” for example, if the URL of the site changes, or
>   the content was moved to a different server.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I was recently working on Drupal multisite to a single site conversion and ran into the same problem. I solved by running this SQL command

```
update `files` set filepath = replace(filepath,'sites/<my_site_name>/files','sites/default/files');
```

which updated the file paths of my files in the files table. You can do something similar for images used in content. I think you need to target the `node_revision` table and the `body` column. So, something like this:

```
update `node_revision` set body = replace(body,'sites/<my_site_name>/files','sites/default/files');
```

[Source](https://drupal.ucsf.edu/single-site-multi-site-conversion-tips)